# Importing a file to a multi-dimensional list in python

Tags: python, list

Apologies, I am new to Python.

I am trying to import a list of products from a file in this format:

> 02154367, "Item 1", 1.45
>
> 38418495, "Item 2", 0.6
>
> 82530174, "Item 3", 0.95

and I need them in python in this format:

`[[02154367,"Item 1",1.45],[38418495,"Item 2",0.6],[82530174,"Item 3",0.95]]`

Any advice would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: csv module will do exactly that for you. Look at the documentation (except for the int/float => string bit, and integers cannot be represented with leading 0!)

Comment: Sure... Read the file, parse the file line by line, store the line in a list, store that list in a master list, read the next line, and repeat with a loop

Comment: Use the `csv` module.  https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader

Answer (score -1):

You can read the `CSV` files with [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html) `read_csv` function. This method creates a dataframe which is an appropriate structure for data processing. But for your desired format, you can transform it to the list of lists.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', header=None)
data = df.values.tolist()
print data
# [[2154367L, ' "Item 1"', 1.45], [38418495L, ' "Item 2"', 0.6], [82530174L, ' "Item 3"', 0.95]]
```

Comment: This is not a problem for `pandas`.  There's no reason to start whipping out the big data tools to do file I/O

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but as I'm in school I can't download other modules. Is there any way I can do this with the 'csv' module? The documentation has confused me a bit. Thanks.

Comment: you can check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19838380/building-list-of-lists-from-csv-file.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Perfectly fine to do that. Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer _"Make sure your answer provides that – or a viable alternative."_

Comment: @PatrickHaugh There is no evidence that the problem is a toy one.